# Use urlparse library to iterate through url param

Tags: python, loops

**I need some help with the following I'm trying to do:**
To modify individual dictionary values for each key (a `param` in this case) for only  a single param at a time with a value from `self.fooz` for each iteration.

**like this**

> So a url like: `somesite.com?id=6&name=Bill` would become
>   `somesite.com?id=<self.fooz>&name=Bill` (iterating for the number of
>   individual foozes) then, `somesite.com?id=6&name=<self.fooz>`
>   (iterating for the number of individual foozes)

Finally, generating a `full_param_vector` and `full_param` values as discussed below

Can someone please help me?

I've done:
1) A set of raw paths are brought in via `self.path_object`)
2) parse the paths after the `?` to grab all the raw parametrized `key/values` (via `parse_after`)

I wrote down some pseudocode of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
if self.path_object is not None:
    dictpath = {}
    for path in self.path_object:
        #path.pathToScan - returns a full url e.g. somesite.com?id=6&name=Bill
        #parse_after returns a string with parameters only, like: {u'id': [u'2'], u'name': [u'Dog']}
        parse_after = urlparse.parse_qs(path.pathToScan[path.pathToScan.find('?') + 1:], keep_blank_values=0, strict_parsing=0)
        #for each params in 'parse_after':
            #replace a key's value from params with a value from self.foozs, 
            #loop over this single key inserting a single value from self.fooz for each param for all fooz_objects, then continue to the next param and do the same
            #create full_param_vector var with these new values
            #construct full_path made up of: path.pathToScan - <part before '?'> + "?" + full_param_vector
            #add all 'full_path' to a dictionary named dictpath
        #print dictpath
```

Any help is welcome. Thank you

Comment: use `query = urlparse.urlparse(path.pathToScan).query; parse_after = urlparse.parse_qs(query, keep_blank_values=0, strict_parsing=0)`

Comment: The issue isnt the `urlparse()` but rather the data. `Path.pathsToScan` returns a full url like `somesite.com/path/here/?param=6&name=Bill` whereas your `query` var just returns the `parameters`. The part that is missing, and is messing all this up is if a path has 1 or more `paths` after the `domain`

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could do the trick, however, I still could not quite parse *your question*

```
from collections import defaultdict
import urllib
import urlparse

# parse the url into parts
parsed = urlparse.urlparse('http://somesite.com/blog/posting/?id=6&name=Bill')

# and parse the query string into a dictionary
qs = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query, keep_blank_values=0, strict_parsing=0)

# this makes a new dictionary, with same keys, but all values changed to "foobar"
foozsified = { i: 'foobar' for i in qs }

# make them back to a query string: id=foobar&name=foobar
quoted = urllib.urlencode(foozsified, doseq=True)

# the original parsed result is a named tuple and cannot be changed,
# make it into a list
parsed = list(parsed)

# replace the 4th element - the query string with our new
parsed[4] = quoted

# and unparse it into a full url    
print(urlparse.urlunparse(parsed))
```

prints

```
http://somesite.com/blog/posting/?id=foobar&name=foobar
```

thus you can do any modifications for the `qs` dictionary there, and then use the `urlunparse` back to a full url.

Comment: So, thanks for the answer, but as included in the question path.pathToScan already outputs a full url e.g. http://somesite.com/blog/posting/?id=foobar&name=foobar . I want to take this path and sub-in values for each param. Does the "Like this" section make sense to you above?

Comment: @CodeTalk it's parsing the URL and parametrizing each querystring parameter in a dictionary. You can then change individual parameters, and then generate a new URL. Isn't that what you want to do?

Comment: @Antti - could you please add some comments to it so I can follow it? Thank you

Comment: Yeah, what I'm trying to do is modify the parameters, but only 1 self.fozz object per url, per param. so like, somesite.com?id=<fozz object>&name=Bill (do that for all the fozz object) for 'id' param.. Then do next param: somesite.com?id=6&name=<fozz object> (do that for all fozz object) for 'name' param. does that make sense to you @MxyL ?  If you have an answer, please feel free to list it too. Thank you both

Comment: done, it is just the matter of what you do for the foozsified dictionary.

Comment: not going to type more since I am over my 200 daily rep limit already.

Comment: I want to replace the values to <fooz objects> in replace of the param val

Comment: This is close to what I was looking for, thanks a lot for this. The one thing is the print statement is printing out the values of params in a urlencoded way, how can I print it out by just the values (not url encoded) ? e.g. id=hi there, instead of id=hi%20there ?